# Find total overlap percent of multiple rectangles overlapping the same rectangle?

Tags: vb.net, intersection, system.drawing, overlap

I've got a list of `System.Drawing.RectangleF` objects that all overlap the same `RectangleF` object. In my picture below, the 3 overlapping rectangles would be the pink, yellow, and red rectangles. My main rectangle in question is the light blue rectangle.

[image]

Second Image:
[image]

I know that with `RectangleF` objects I can use the `Intersect()` method that will return me another `RectangleF` object representing the overlap. But as far as I can tell, this only really works when comparing two rectangles.

**My question is**: How could I determine the TOTAL area/percentage (i.e. the *combined total overlap* of the red, yellow, and pink rectangles when compared to the light blue rectangle - but it would need to be smart enough to not count the area in which the red and yellow overlaps *twice*, and same for the pink and yellow)?

**NOTE: The green lines represent the area I'm looking for, just the total area of the blue rectangle that is not visible.**

**UPDATE**: I've added a 2nd image to further demonstrate what I'm looking for. In the second image, the presence of the burgundy rectangle should have no affect on the total percent covered because that area is already covered by the yellow and green rectangles.

Comment: Fun question, took me a few minutes to come up with an approach.  Is this homework?

Comment: It's actually for my job - and it has me stuck. The jist of it is that I need to identify "hidden" rectangles, those that are either completely overlapped or almost completely overlapped. Right now I'm trying to find the area so that I can identify rectangles that are 90% covered (or more).

Comment: Just to be sure I understand this, you need to total area that overlaps the blue rectangle without double counting any of the other rectangles which also overlap the same space.  Right?

Comment: @HolgerBrandt - correct. I just need to know what Percent of the blue rectangle is covered (or visible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I think I found a solution using a `Region` that seems to be working for both of my example images above:

```
Private Function TotalCoveredAreaPercent(ByVal oRectToCheck As RectangleF, ByVal oOverlappingRects As List(Of RectangleF)) As Double

    Dim oRegion As New Region(oRectToCheck)
    Dim dTotalVisibleArea As Double = 0
    Dim dTotalCoveredArea As Double = 0

    'now we need to exclude the intersection of our 
    'overlapping rectangles with our main rectangle:
    For Each oOverlappingRect As RectangleF In oOverlappingRects

        oRegion.Exclude(RectangleF.Intersect(oRectToCheck, oOverlappingRect))

    Next

    'now we have access to the non-overlapping 
    'rectangles that make up the visible area of our main rectangle:
    Dim oVisibleRects As RectangleF()

    oVisibleRects = oRegion.GetRegionScans(New Drawing2D.Matrix())

    'add the area of the visible rectangles together 
    'to find the total visible area of our main rectangle:
    For Each oVisibleRect As RectangleF In oVisibleRects
        dTotalVisibleArea += AreaOf(oVisibleRect)
    Next

    Dim dPercentVisible As Double = dTotalVisibleArea / AreaOf(oRectToCheck) * 100

    'percent covered is 100 - the visible percentage:
    Return (100 - dPercentVisible)

End Function
```

This seems to be working pretty well, and is quite simple.

Comment: Never had use of Regions before.  Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I actually tried Regions first, but wasn't sure on how to use them exactly - and I hadn't seen the GetRegionScans() method. I had read online that with C++ you could convert the byte array returned in GetRegionData.Data to a structure of non-overlapping rectangles that represent the visible portion of your rectangle. However, I couldn't find a way to do that in .NET. Luckily I gave it another look with the help of a co-worker and we came up with this. Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: I was starting to go the exclusion route except with rectangles and using a recursion routine when I saw your answer.  Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my algorithm.  The key point is that we are subtracting out overlaps of overlaps.

```
    Dim baseRect As New RectangleF(10, 10, 20, 20)
    Dim otherRectList As New List(Of RectangleF)
    otherRectList.Add(New RectangleF(5, 5, 10, 10))
    otherRectList.Add(New RectangleF(20, 20, 10, 10))
    otherRectList.Add(New RectangleF(10, 5, 10, 10))

    Dim overlapRectList As New List(Of RectangleF)
    For Each otherRect As RectangleF In otherRectList
      If RectangleF.Intersect(otherRect, baseRect) <> RectangleF.Empty Then
        overlapRectList.Add(RectangleF.Intersect(otherRect, baseRect))
      End If
    Next

    Dim totalArea As Single = 0
    For Each overlapRect As RectangleF In overlapRectList
      totalArea += overlapRect.Width * overlapRect.Height
    Next

    'Subtract out any overlaps that overlap each other
    For i = 0 To overlapRectList.Count - 2
      For j = i+1 To overlapRectList.Count - 1
        If i <> j Then
          If RectangleF.Intersect(overlapRectList(i), overlapRectList(j)) <> RectangleF.Empty Then
            Dim dupeRect As RectangleF = RectangleF.Intersect(overlapRectList(i), overlapRectList(j))
            totalArea -= dupeRect.Width * dupeRect.Height         
          End If
        End If
      Next
    Next
```

I amended the code to take into account tcarvin's note.  However, I have not plotted out the results on graph paper to see if this is fully correct.  I will look at it as soon as I have additional time.  Also note that I have not included any code to handle a situation with less than 2 intersections.

Comment: Same mistake I made with the subtraction.  Given rectangles A, B, C, and D all overlapping each other (and overlapping base rect Z), the subtract loop decrements the overlap on each pass. So rect D for example might add 10 to the area but then subtract 10 on each pass (for A, B, and C).

Comment: Thank you for the code but like @tcarvin mentioned, too many decrements happen. For example, on Image 2 above, you should get the exact same results whether the burgundy rectangle in the middle is present or not (it doesn't cover any area that isn't already covered).